# Dynamic list to match Asset Numbers with Asset Names

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, dynamic-arrays

I have a list of assets and asset numbers, they are not sorted in alphabetical order. I want all the assets with same names to have the same asset numbers. Please see below: Column AY is the Asset names and Column AZ is asset numbers. They need to look like below. I tried =IF(AY17=$AY$16:AY16,AZ16,AZ16+1) as an array formula, it doesn't work.

Please let me know if you have an idea

```
Asset   Asset Number 
Apple       1
Google      2
Microsoft   3
EMC         4
Microsoft   3
Google      2
Samsung     5
Apple       1
```

Answer (score 0):

formula for `AZ2`: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(AY2,AY$2:AZ1,2,0),MAX(AZ$2:AZ1)+1)`
(the $ are essential, this is a standard, non-array formula)
drag or copy down.